# Setting active section in accordion

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am trying to set an active section within my accordion. I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to do this. I have searched tirelessly, and did not find a solution to my specific case. It seems very straight forward, but i cant figure it out. please help!

(my intention is to put this list on the masterpage and have each content page set the active section when navigated to.)

I have saved my accordion list to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pWbxm/14/

** alternate accordion list on jsFiddle, that uses the div/header format:  http://jsfiddle.net/hemiar/44UTR/

html:

```
<ul class="leftNavMenu">
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="#">HR + Benefits</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HR Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employee Handbook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Managers</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li><a href="#" title="#">Departments</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Accounting</a>  
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Accounting Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Draft Dates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">InfoSend</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">Acquisitions</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Acquisitions Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bulk Acquisitions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dealer Program Acquisitions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Training Manual</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Contacts</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SAFE Phone List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSAI Phone List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DND Codes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Phone User Guides</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.leftNavMenu{width: 195px;}

ul.leftNavMenu{line-height: 0.5em;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;}

ul.leftNavMenu li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;
    color:#1D65B3;
    border-bottom:inset;
    border-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#BDD1E6;}

ul.leftNavMenu li a{
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
    display: block;}

ul.leftNavMenu li a:hover{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#1D65B3;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    font-family:Verdana, "Segoe UI";
    font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#D5E6F8;
    color:#ffffff;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul li a{
    padding-left: 15px;
    outline:0;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#1D65B3;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul ul li{    
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#1D65B3;
    border-bottom-style:dotted;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul ul li a{
    font-size:9px;font-weight:normal;
    padding-left: 30px;}

ul.leftNavMenu ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#E8EFF7;
    color:#1D65B3;}

ul.leftNavMenu span{
    float:right;}
```

JScript

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').click(function(ev) {
            $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle('slow')
                .end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp('slow');
            ev.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
    var accordion = $('ul.leftNavMenu');
    accordion.accordion('activate', 2);
```

Comment: Have you looked in the JS console for error messages ?

Comment: Hans... Yes I looked and there are no errors listed. The page loads fine without any errors, but it does not activate any sections. could it be that my sections have to be labled somehow or must I reference the sections a different way? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your jsFiddle produces "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'" in the JS console when run. It seems to me that you are trying to use the JQuery UI accordian feature but you have not leaded the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I forgot to select the jQuery UI framework (I have updated the jfiddle url above), thats why you were getting the typeError. I have fixed it, but the problem remains ofcourse. I will continue to look for an answer to my problem. I really appreciate your response and anyone elses help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this question has been left open for a couple of years. I was able to get it working to the tertiary nav menu using the div and header tags, but not with the ul tags. It seems that it will only recognize the first and second levels in a ul list.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI Accordion is designed to work with the HTML that is shown in the documentation. I don't think that it will work with `<ul><li>` tags.

You should maybe look at re-writing your html to use their markup. e.g.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        More Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using the div/ header tag format illustrated in the UI documentation, and I got it to work to the second level in the menu but I need three levels. the third menu just wont show up. I've been trying, frustratingly so, for the last 2 days, and im about ready to snap. I would be eternally grateful to anyone who could definatively tell me if activating a panel using a ul/li format is possible, and If not, please post an example of a simple 3 layer div/header format that works. Thank you all.  I've also added the jsFiddle of my progress using the div/header format to my post above.